# Unable to install the Outlook Addin Manifest with Mobile support

Tags: manifest, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I tried multiple Documentions for the mobile support manifest file snippets, I dont see any complete example on the Microsoft documention which shows the complete standards of versionOveriding.
Till now with help of documentation I reached till the below manifest code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <OfficeApp 
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" 
       xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1"
      xsi:type="MailApp">

  <!-- Begin Basic Settings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided. -->

  <!-- IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you reuse this manifest ensure that you change this id to a new GUID. -->
  <Id>0ee7b924-eb57-414f-aeb3-0230b6a768ce</Id>

  <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change. -->
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>ABC</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>de-de</DefaultLocale>

  <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Value" >
  <Override Locale="en-US" Value="VALUE"/>
  </DisplayName>
  <Description DefaultValue=
   "DISCRIPTION">
   <Override Locale="en-US" Value=
   "DISCRIPTION" />
</Description>

  <!-- Icon for your add-in. Used on installation screens and the add-ins dialog. -->
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/assets/retriever-icon-32.png" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/assets/retriever-hi-res-icon.png"/>

  <!--If you plan to submit this add-in to the Office Store, uncomment the SupportUrl element below-->
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl" />

  <!-- Domains that will be allowed when navigating. For example, if you use ShowTaskpane and then have an href link, navigation will only be allowed if the domain is on this list. -->
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>~remoteAppUrl</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>~remoteAppUrl</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain3</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <!--End Basic Settings. -->

  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/#archived_mail_retrieve"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>

  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>

  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">

    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">

        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <!-- Location of the Functions that UI-less buttons can trigger (ExecuteFunction Actions). -->
          <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />

          <!-- Message Read -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                    <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ButtonCommands to learn how to add more Controls: ExecuteFunction and Menu -->
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
          <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ExtensionPointsCommands to learn how to add more Extension Points: MessageRead, AppointmentOrganizer, AppointmentAttendee -->
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>

    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/assets/retriever-icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/assets/retriever-icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/assets/retriever-icon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/function-file/function-file.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/#archived_mail_retrieve"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="BOO-Addin-Group"/>
        <bt:String id="customTabLabel"  DefaultValue="BOO-Archiver-Tab"/>
        <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="BOO-Archived-Retriever"/>
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="BOO-Archived-Retriever"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="BOO Archived-Retriever hilft beim Lesen des archivierten Mail-Inhalts.">

        </bt:String>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
     <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
          <MobileFormFactor>
            <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MobileMessageReadCommandSurface">
              <Group id="mobileMsgRead">
                <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
              <Control id="mblRestButton" xsi:type="MobileButton">
                <Label resid="mblButtonLabel"/>
                <Icon xsi:type="bt:MobileIconList">
                  <bt:Image size="25" scale="1" resid="green-icon-32" />
                  <bt:Image size="25" scale="2" resid="green-icon-32" />
                  <bt:Image size="25" scale="3" resid="green-icon-32" />

                  <bt:Image size="32" scale="1" resid="green-icon-32" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" scale="2" resid="green-icon-32" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" scale="3" resid="green-icon-32" />

                  <bt:Image size="48" scale="1" resid="green-icon-32" />
                  <bt:Image size="48" scale="2" resid="green-icon-32" />
                  <bt:Image size="48" scale="3" resid="green-icon-32" />
                </Icon>
                <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                  <SourceLocation resid="restMobileTaskPaneUrl"/>
                </Action>
              </Control>
              </Group>
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </MobileFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>

      <Resources>
        <bt:Images>
          <!-- Green icon -->
          <bt:Image id="green-icon-16" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/icon16.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="green-icon-32" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/icon32.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="green-icon-80" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/icon80.png"/>
        </bt:Images>
        <bt:Urls>
          <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/FunctionFile/Functions.html"/>
          <bt:Url id="restMobileTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/home.html"/>
        </bt:Urls>
        <bt:ShortStrings>
          <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="Add-in Demo"/>
          <!-- Read mode -->
          <bt:String id="mblButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Test REST Calls"/>
        </bt:ShortStrings>
      </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

after I upload this with all perfect remote urls and value , I get the error message

[image]

More Information: I also found the same question Link:[Same Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52589129/outlook-web-add-in-manifest-change-to-support-mobile-devices-mobileformfactor) asking but I cannot understand the solution there as there is no Answer explained for the others who are browsing the internet for such issues.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add DesktopFormFactor to versionOverrides as well.